# How to read the computer security token to get group membership

Tags: kerberos, windows-identity, group-membership

I can read the user account token using:

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

And then get the groups the account is a member of.

How can I read the computer account token to get the group membership?

Answers relying on querying Active Directory are not what I am looking for.

Tried:

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().DeviceClaims
```

but it's an empty collection.